# For a charged particle, how many times can you accelerate its acceleration?

Tags: electromagnetism, acceleration

A charged particle's acceleration in the electric field of a uniform, simply connected, and three-dimensional charge distribution is changed (getting bigger or smaller depending on the signs of the particles charge and the charge of the distribution) while approaching the distribution. In other words, the acceleration of the charged particle (which can also be the source of e.m. radiation, the "Bremsstrahlung", but let's ignore that for the moment, and assume the particle is making it's way to the charge distribution in a straight line) is accelerated.

We can accelerate the acceleration of the acceleration of the particle by adding more charge to the charge distribution (or keeping the acceleration constant by taking charge away in the distribution, which can be the base for another question, namely *how* to take the charge away from the distribution to keep the acceleration of the charge constant).

Now is there a way to accelerate the last acceleration, i.e to accelerate the acceleration of the acceleration of the acceleration or even make more accelerations of accelerations occur? I can't think of no charge distribution, changing in time and place or form to let this happen. Can it be done?

Comment: The accelerations of acceleration you talk about all have names. The derivative of acceleration with respect to time, for instance, is called Jerk.

Comment: Do I understand the question correctly as: "Is there any charge distribution $\rho(x,t)$ such that the third time derivative of the acceleration of a test charge will be nonzero"?

Comment: I do indeed mean the third derivative of the acceleration towards the charge distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Put a particle in an electric field (as generated by e.g. a capacitor) and ramp up/down the charge on the capacitor (and hence the electric field) in ways such that the first (second, third, whatever) time derivative is non-zero. This is already the case for the ordinary charging of a capacitor by a constant voltage, where the dependence of charge on time is exponential and therefore *all* derivatives of acceleration are non-zero, so there is nothing special about this situation at all.